# Mute everything except my application in C#

Tags: c#

I have made a C# app with a Speech Synthesis part. I would like to, when the speech narrator thingy is speaking, mute (or lower the volume of) all other applications. This is because, with background music, it can sometimes be tricky to hear the narrator.

How do I do it?

For the rest I've already set up the speak started and completed event handlers.

Comment: I would be surprise and in a bad way if some applications start controlling sound volume of my computer, even for a good reason.

Comment: It could also be a bad surprise that an app can’t do that at all (unless you’re using an iPhone). I mean I’m sure some apps can control the main volume, maybe through advanced low-level trickery?

Comment: Wow good spot @Matt

Comment: Up-voters should perhaps take a refresher of [ask]